# woocommerce_thankyou. how to get a variable (from a plugin) into it

Tags: php, wordpress, oop, woocommerce

I am building a WooCommerce payment plugin.

In the process, it will produce a payment code that should be displayed in the "thank you" page.

Here is the snippet

```
class WC_Gateway_Finpay extends WC_Payment_Gateway {

  public function process_payment( $order_id ) {
    global $woocommerce;

    $order = new WC_Order($order_id);

    $response = $this->generate_request($order_id);

    $payment_code = $response->payment_code;

    return array(
      'result'  => 'success',
      'redirect' => $this->get_return_url( $order )
    );
  }


  public function thankyou_page() {
    echo '<p>Lorem ipsum dolor si amett '.$payment_code.'</p>';
  }

}
```

How can I get the the `$payment_code` in to `thankyou_page()` ?

Comment: You are defining a class inside a function that's hooked to `finpay_gateway_init`, defining the relevant variable in in a **method inside that class** (no idea if the method is going to run at all), and then you need to access that variable in a different function hooked in a different action hook? Something doesn't smell right here...

Comment: `$this->generate_request($order_id);` this code generate dynamic ID?

Comment: udpated the code